# Set-AzContext works in Azure Cloud Shell but doesn't in Azure PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-cloud-shell

When i execute following command

```
Clear-AzureProfile
Connect-AzAccount -TenantID xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

in `Azure PowerShell` i get this error.

```
Set-AzContext : Please provide a valid tenant or a valid subscription.
At line:6 char:1
+ Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

and if i run the same command in `Azure Cloud Shell` it works

```
Name        Account         SubscriptionName    Environment    TenantId         
xxxx        xxxxxxx         xxxx                 xxxx             xxxx
```

I switched from free-trial to pay-as-you-go subscription and using credentials for pay-as-you-go in both environment but it doesn't work. can anyone help

Comment: you need to login first

Comment: @4c74356b41. Thanks.  i edited my question with complete details and still the same issue

Comment: update to latest module version, check your permissions. you probably do not have rights

Comment: Close your powershell and open a new one, or use `Clear-AzContext`, not `Clear-AzureProfile`. Then use `Connect-AzAccount -Tenant xxxxx -Subscription xxxxx`.

Comment: @4c74356b41. If i do not have rights then how I can create resources in cloud shell and Azure Portal

Comment: you might be using a different user

Comment: @JoyWang. Thanks. your suggestion worked, i used Clear-AzContext  instead of Clear-AzureProfile at the top of script and then Connect-AzAccount and every resource in the script created successfully. Please move your comments into answer

Comment: @4c74356b41. same user in both environments and it was caching issue because i used Clear-AzContext as suggested by Joy and it worked

Comment: Related post - [The subscription of xxx' doesn't exist in cloud 'AzureCloud'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51911225/465053)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Close your powershell and open a new one, or use `Clear-AzContext`, not `Clear-AzureProfile`. Then use `Connect-AzAccount -Tenant xxxxx -Subscription xxxxx`, it should work.

Comment: Could you also put this answer for my following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56689736/azure-powershell-script-does-not-work-when-change-to-a-different-azure-subscript?as this is the same issue

Comment: @3355307 I added it to that question.

Comment: I think you should also specify how to get TenantId and SubscriptionID for those trying to login first time. In my case I had to switch to `AZ CLI` and use: `az account show -otable` and `az account list -otable`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are cycling through subscriptions in the same tenant and don't want to have to sign in with `Connect-AzAccount` multiple times, the following worked for me to switch between subscriptions:

```
Remove-AzContext -InputObject (Get-AzContext) -Force | Out-Null;
$sub = Set-AzContext -Subscription $_.SubscriptionName;
```

Before adding the `Remove-AzContext` statement I was seeing that `Set-AzContext` was not actually switching the context to another subscription for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have this problem too, and my solution was different that one provided on top of this.
Apparently, in our Azure Cloud Shell, we have several contexts available, so, we don't have to set the context (using `Set-AzContext`), but to switch to one or other context, using `Select-AzContext`)

I can list the contexts using

```
Get-AzContext -ListAvailable
```

Then choose one using the

```
Select-AzContext -Name ...
```

For-example, in scripts, I use this one-line command to switch to the subscription having ID $SubscriptionID :

```
Select-AzContext -name ((Get-AzContext -ListAvailable).Name -match $SubscriptionId)[0]
```

Not elegant, but efficient

I don't know why we are in such situation. Maybe because we are administrating using invited accounts from another tenant.

Hope this help someone in same situation than us.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue and just needed to login via powershell with

Connect-AzAccount -Tenant $tenantId -Subscription $subscriptionId